# How can I move files from one folder to another created at specific date giving the creation date in redhat

Tags: linux, terminal

I am trying to use terminal to move files from one folder to another using creation date.

I am using the script

```
find /root/call_log/files23 -type f -newermt 2022-06-01 -not -newermt 2022-06-02 -exec mv {} /archive
```

/root/call_log/files23 is location ...
/archive is destination
but getting an error missing argument -exec. How can i fix it or is there a better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

`man find` gives me following information:

> -cnewer reference
>
> > Time  of the last status change of the current file is more recent than that of the last data modification of the reference file.  If reference is a symbolic link and the -H option or the -L option  is  in effect, then the time of the last data modification of the file it points to is always used.

I propose you use this instead of `-newermt`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move all files in a given folder according to when **they were created and not according to the last change**, this command will do the work:

```
find /path/to/source/directory -type f -newermt YYYY-MM-DD -exec mv {} /path/to/target/directory \;
```

Just replace **/path/to/source/directory** and **/path/to/target/directory** with proper absolute locations.
**YYYY-MM-DD** replace with the desired creation date.